# quotes in batch recursive for /f loop not parsing

Tags: parsing, batch-file, for-loop, recursion, escaping

I have a problem. It's kind of hard to explain, so I'll just show the code.

```
for /r "%1" %%X in (*) do (
    REM ...
    for %%Y in (some strings here) do (
        REM ...
        for /f "delims=" %%Z in ('"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z" l -slt "%2"^|findstr /c:"Packed Size = "') do (
            REM ... the line above is causing the problem.
            echo %%Z
            )
        )
    REM ...
    )
)
```

Basically, the quotes around the path to 7-Zip aren't being parsed properly, and I've tried several different combinations of carets and quotes, but they all throw a variety of errors. Batch was never meant to do this kind of thing, I know, but is there any way of getting this to work?

Edit: copying the 7-zip executables to a folder (without spaces) in the batch's location makes it run fine, so it's definitely that, but I'd like to avoid having to have multiple copies of the same program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a little trick:

```
for /f "delims=" %%Z in ('call "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z" l -slt "%2"^|findstr /c:"Packed Size = "') do ( echo %%Z )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z" l -slt "%2"|for /f "delims=" %%Z in ('findstr /c:"Packed Size = "') do (
        REM ... the line above is causing the problem.
        echo %%Z
        )
```

Comment: Hey, I can't believe I didn't think of trying this! Didn't you answer one of my earlier questions too?

Comment: Oh, it turns out it doesn't work exactly the way I wanted it to. I should have been more specific, sorry.